# Parse a JSON file with ISODate in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file with some lines like:

`"updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-20T09:32:16.732+0000"),`

I tried `json.loads` but it has an error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 13 (char 15)`.

I believe that the problem is at `ISODate ()` but how could I handle that with Python?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not valid JSON, to begin with. I guess the `ISODATE("...")` is generated from MongoDB, maybe dumping the `ISODate()` helper directly instead of its string representation into the JSON?

In any case, you could use a regex on the whole JSON-string to get rid of the `ISODate("...")`, retrieve the date as a string and then use `python-dateutil` to parse the value to a `datetime.datetime`.

Something to the tune of

```
import json
import dateutil.parse
import re
json_str = ....
clean_json = re.compile('ISODate\(("[^"]+")\)').sub('\\1', json_str)
json_obj = json.loads(clean_json)
# use dateutil.parser.parse(s) to parse each date into a datetime.datetime
```